# Puppet manifest - 'sudo' commands?

Tags: ruby, manifest, puppet, vagrant

I have a CentOS base box in Vagrant that I'm standing up with a puppet manifest. Here's what's in the manifest so far:

```
class base {
    exec { "sudocmd":
        path => ["/usr/bin/","/usr/sbin/","/bin"],
        command => "sudo yum update -y",
    }

    package { "man":
        ensure => present,
    }

    package { "bind":
        ensure => present,
    }

    package { "bind-utils":
        ensure => present,
    }
}

include base
```

But when I say `vagrant up`, I get an error that sudocmd `yum update` exited with a 1. I've looked on the web, but I haven't found a solution for this yet. Any help?

========EDIT=========
I read the answers and I agree - thanks guys. I'm just using this on a dev box to mess around and I needed it to be up to date before I started doing work on it.

Answer (score 11):

With puppet, you shouldn't need to use `sudo`, just run the `yum` command directly. Normally commands will run as root by default, but you can specify what user.

```
exec { "sudocmd":
    path => ["/usr/bin/","/usr/sbin/","/bin"],
    command => "yum update -y",
    user => root,
}
```

However, I strongly recommend that you do not use any kind of non-conditional `exec` with puppet. That will run every time puppet runs. As [Forrest already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14095425), it's not what puppet is designed for. I wouldn't use puppet for a `yum update`, and my `exec`s always have `creates`, `onlyif`, `refreshonly` or `unless` to ensure they only run when needed.

Answer (score 3):

So Puppet isn't really meant to perform tasks like a yum update. It's a configuration management tool, not something that completely replaces this sort of task. In addition you run into a lot of issues with this. What if Puppet is daemonized? Will this negatively impact our production environment? What happens if a user accidentally runs Puppet and it updates a package that breaks our scripts (JDK, MySQL, PHP, etc.). As far as I'm aware there is no solution to this because it's not really considered a problem. Scott Pack over on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/411049/how-to-yum-update-aptitude-safe-upgrade-many-hosts) provided a very descriptive answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

updating "path" attribute helps me. sudo and apt-get commands are available in **/usr/bin/** path

```
exec { 'autoclean':
        command   => 'apt-get autoclean',
        path      => '/usr/local/bin/:/bin/:/usr/bin/',
        cwd       => '/home',
}
```

my puppet version: 5.5.1